# WSO2 Identity server logout not working version 6.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have used the below request to WSO2 Idenity server.
https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=id_token_hint&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://www.google.ca/. Identity server is re-directing to google. however once i have enter my client URL it is logging me back in directly.
Any leads would be appreciated.

I have tried enabling logger and I could not find any logs related to WSO2 .

Comment: Could you please share the configured login options in your application and inbound protocol configurations (Oauth/oidc configs) with masking senstibe data